# Magento2 Model fields from 2 tables

Tags: magento2, model

I have a simple model for example

```
ID     Name
1     nerogee
2     John
```

Another table save **age** information by reference Key **ID**

```
ID     age
1       20
2       31
```

I try to build a listing and form. But I failed to get the **age** field for the model. Can anyone give me some hint on how to do this? I checked the **cms_page** module and find it seem something to do with **MetadataPool** and **ExtensionPool**. But I still can't get it work.